# Performance Concepts: WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, treeview

So, I'm writing a JSON viewer in WPF (I know there are a few out there, but I want more out of them and I want to use it as both a learning opportunity and a personal project).  Since it's JSON, I want it to be able to hold vast amounts of data.  I'm displaying everything in a TreeView, but the UX is starting to fall over when I get a lot of data.  Not even a TON -- we're talking loading 89k of JSON here, though that 89k represents a little over 4000 nodes right now.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to display it all in a tree pre-expanded the first time the user gets there.  However, I'm unhappy with how WPF is handling that many nodes in a TreeView and I'm not sure what to do about it.

I started with the `VirtualizingStackPanel` (`IsVirtualized` and `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`).  Those did a pretty good job of things, but it made scrolling wonky -- since new data comes in pre-expanded (via a style right now that sets each `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` to true), the scrollbar tends to jump up and down while the user scrolls down in the window.  On the bright side, the window loads up more-or-less instantly.

I know I don't have code in this post, but my question is more conceptual: what are some mitigating strategies I can use to fix this?  Here's what I've come up with so far:

- **Load everything collapsed**: Don't bother pre-expanding stuff.  This is the route I am least enthusiastic about.  Sure, it will help with particularly large data sets, but the small data sets will require manual expansion, and I'm suspecting that's the more common case.
- **Load everything collapsed if there are more than N nodes**: This could work from a UX standpoint, though the value of N would be fairly arbitrary.  I've seen the TreeView start to stutter after 790 nodes, so that apparently is a problem point; I'd have to do some more research into exactly where the breakpoint would be.
- **Lazy loading**: Load nodes on-demand.  Nodes would load very quickly -- I'm playing with JSON in memory, after all -- but it suffers from exactly the same problem as the first idea, loading everything collapsed.
- **Expand only the first node**: Seems rather arbitrary, really.  Plus, if the first node was particularly large, we're back to square one.
- **Expand everything in the background and show a loading screen or something**: Would that even work?  Can I push a UI thread to a background thread, or affect the UI on a background thread while I show a spinner or something?  Never tried it -- my development career has always run into "This is the UI thread.  Never hold it up."  It never occurred to me that you could even *have* two UI threads.  Does anyone know if you can?
- **Hide the control, load data into it, and show it when loading is done**: Two problems with this.  First, I'd have to figure out how I know when loading is done (I'm using binding here, so I'm not going through a method whose exit I can detect).  Second, would it make any difference, or would it fall over as soon as it's un-hidden and starts rendering?  That one I can look into.
- **Give up and take a vacation in the Carribbean**: Because why not?

Comment: I think the correct approach is : Expand everything in the background and show a loading screen or something.  But you are backwards.  The background process would send nodes up to main thread using OnProgress() method.